# Have I damaged my arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno

I was trying to build a finger print lock system.. While my arduino was connected with my pc, I mistakenly plugged the adapter and turned it on. I immediately switched it off. It was working fine (port 3?) Now suddenly port 3 disappeared and the only available option I have is port 1, which is not working! My window is also alerting me that it didn't recognize the device. I searched for it in device manger but no others devices option is available

Comment: or you damaged the USB port. what adapter and how did you plug it?

Comment: 12v 2A power adapter. I plugged it into the port in the board that is given for adapter.

Comment: on genuine Arduino Uno it shouldn't cause a problem

Comment: I probably didn't burn it as the solinoid lock and the sensor is perfectly working and when I connect the USB, my arduino uno gets power. Im not just able to upload any code as there is no port 3 option to select.

Answer (score 0):

Which model of Arduino?

The design of most models has circuitry that handles getting power from both the barrel connector and the USB port, and switches between them intelligently.

Thus the answer should be "no, no problem." However, what else does your 12 adapter power? You might want to post a full circuit diagram of your project.

Also, as Juraj says, Arduino brand microcontrollers are designed to handle this situation. Knockoff models may cut corners.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/mobile/folders/1JWxkBoONwUHxvn-4A6pfhs0_0sCHIo5Q?usp=drive_open     I'm following the circuit and the codes given in this drive. Its arduino uno r3. The Solenoid lock and the sensor is perfectly working as i already uploaded my codes. But I was trying to reload it again so that I can start everything from the beginning. Collecting ids and all that ... but r3 port has completely disappeared from the option and this is why I'm not able to upload any new code.